# Bash: Newlines in output of code

Tags: bash, hash

Here's the code I have right now:
It seems to be inserting newlines before the hash output from some bizarre reason that I can't figure out.

```
hash=$(printf "$pswdOne\n$pswdTwo"|grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2 |awk '{print $7}')
myname=$(whoami)

echo "" > ./testoutput
printf "set superusers=\"$myname\"" >> ./testoutput
printf "\npassword_pbkdf2 $myname $hash" >> ./testoutput
```

Here's the output:

```
set superusers="thornegarvin"
password_pbkdf2 thornegarvin 

grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.03266E0763AA0C4E3D97C6DEA85DFBC4D34F97630C9FDE42B53E66D900341FF9F0988A7161C5A8B8EFA88AC33B1A06D459B6DA4D066EAB0EAC6B398DFF5FC3BB.614FE51D9ABB0D81695D080F9DF234FE05AB2955F485EC314917764D7E0DC3F3CC239F8C26DE36A8418E33CB89085312F0A9B6E283C407A4B8B3A2C1BC91C7F6
```

Comment: What is the output of `printf "==%s==\n" "$hash"`? (Note that it's good practice to use `%s` rather than interpolation for parameter values, to guard against the possibility that the parameter value itself contains `%` sequences. I don't think that's an issue here, though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your output for `printf "$pswdOne\n$pswdTwo"|grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2`  You'll find 3 lines outputted:

```
$ printf "test\ntest"|grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2
Enter password:
Reenter password:
PBKDF2 hash of your password is grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.A4ED2A115DD054DD002C6C70189AEE5DB2E737D4126BC15BD317EDD3A12FE9A1F1ED30AAEA6B223ABA19D5168867B57455491EB7B8E7B73FC0EAB617EC915B82.3C97F68C849082874FB72AB5DA50C1E33975894E1209D0E0FFAF23B784CC6E63E4D62778BC2917834E689C192DCE29D8E1620DFC4C2E97D447B89E3651AC829E
```

When you `awk '{print $7}'` that you'll get two null records which will just be line feeds and then your hash. Instead do something like:

```
printf "test\ntest"|grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $7}'
```

or

```
printf "test\ntest"|grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2 | awk '$1=="PBKDF2"{print $7}'
```

Comment: or `awk '/g/{print $7}'` and you can use echo -e instead of printf: `echo -e "hi\nhi\n" | grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2 | awk '/g/{print $7}'`

Comment: I've never used `/g/`. Christ that's handy as hell. I've got some code to go update.

Comment: I was using printf for compatibility between versions and also because it lets me control output format more precisely. Thanks for the /g/ tip though, did not know that.